# How to wrap observable inside another observable in RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I want to wrap retrofit api call in another method where I can additionally show/hide loader, check for network etc. As my api returns observable, the way I ended up is below:

```
private <T> Observable<T> request(final Observable<T> apiCall, final ViewManager viewManager) {
    return Observable.create(new Action1<Emitter<T>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Emitter<T> emitter) {
            if (!NetworkUtils.isConnected(context)) {
                emitter.onError(new ConnectException("network not connected"));
                return;
            }
            viewManager.showLoader();
            apiCall.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<T>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            viewManager.hideLoader();
                            emitter.onCompleted();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            viewManager.hideLoader();
                            emitter.onError(e);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(T response) {
                            emitter.onNext(response);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
}
```

Is this a standard way of dealing with the problem? How do you wrap an observable inside another observable? Can anyone guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the idiomatic way with reactive extensions is to use **composition**, and this is one of the great powers of RX.

first let's define the desired behaviors using operators, what you want is something like this:

```
apiCall
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .startWith(Observable.defer(() -> {
      if (!NetworkUtils.isConnected(context)) {
          return Observable.error(new ConnectException("network not connected"));
      } else {
          return Observable.empty();
      }
  }))
  .doOnSubscribe(() -> viewManager.showLoader())
  .doOnCompleted(() -> viewManager.hideLoader())
  .doOnError(throwable -> viewManager.hideLoader());
```

now, for composing it to any network apiCall Observable, you can use `compose()` operator and encapsulate this logic into `Transformer` for that:

```
class CustomTransformer<T> implements Observable.Transformer<T, T> {

    private final ViewManager viewManager;
    private final Context context;

    CustomTransformer(ViewManager viewManager, Context context) {
        this.viewManager = viewManager;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> apiCall) {
        return apiCall
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .startWith(Observable.defer(() -> {
                    if (!NetworkUtils.isConnected(context)) {
                        return Observable.error(new ConnectException("network not connected"));
                    } else {
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }
                }))
                .doOnSubscribe(() -> viewManager.showLoader())
                .doOnCompleted(() -> viewManager.hideLoader())
                .doOnError(throwable -> viewManager.hideLoader());
        ;
    }
}
```

then you can compose it with any network `Observable`:

```
someRetrofitQuery
   .compose(new CustomTransformer<>(viewManager, context))
    ...
   .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if I do not use compose() and just subscribe that observable in presenter. I will need just an extra parameter for ViewManager. I did not understand why you need compose

Comment: you can also just replace your method content with my suggested content  (and have the same signature), this will apply the same effect, as I said, using compose is the more idiomatic way in reactive approach, as it is not 'breaking' the chain with methods the wrap it, you can read here http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/

Comment: or you can use Kotlin to make that function as a extension function for Observable.

Comment: @yosriz   doOnSubscribe(() -> viewManager.showLoader()) creates problem because if it is subscribed on io(), showLoader doesn't work.

Comment: @yosriz where exactly? before doOnSubscribe? can you edit your code and help me understand?

Comment: You can use this to validate your dialog:   if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
  // On UI thread.
} else {
  // Not on UI thread.
}